# Call a NOT registered DLL with PHP

Tags: php, dll

I must use a DLL developed by a third party and I want to use it from PHP code. I am already using it with C++ code and it's all ok, but the DLL cannot be registered under Windows apparently because it hasn't got an entry point.

In C++ I use this code to call the DLL without registering it:

`hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Users\\blablabla\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\blablabla\\blablabla.dll"));`

`FARPROC MainCommand = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hinstLib),"blablaCommand");`

Is it possible to do the same in PHP?

Comment: Consider creating php extension wrapper dll

Comment: [Read this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)

Comment: I tried but no extension appears on the php.info() and within error logs I find the following: "<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_DasNet.dll' - %1 non è un'applicazione di Win32 valida." (translated from the Italian: "is not a valid Win32 application"). Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a PHP extension, PHP doesn't utilise FFI and doesn't have a native interface.